# find conflicts with subversive API

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I am writing an eclipse plug-in to update some projects in my workspace. After the update, there may be conflicts. I want to show a dialog to the user if there are some conflicts in the updated project(s).

To update, I use the `UpdateOperation`, then I do a IResource.refreshLocal() on the updated project. To look for conflicts I use `FileUtility.checkForResourcesPresenceRecursive(resources, IStateFilter.SF_CONFLICTING)`. Also tryed with `IStateFilter.SF_CONTENT_CONFLICTING` and `IStateFilter.SF_TREE_CONFLICTING`. Normally they return `false`.

When I run in debug mode, the first two return `true`. That brings me to think that there is some event that gets fired after the refresh and with the loss of time in debug mode, Subversive gets to know about it. Am I right ? What event is this ? It is not `IResourceChangeEvent`. Tryed to listen for `POST_CHANGED` with no luck.

Do you have a hint for me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I expected. The `UpdateOperation` (and also the `CommitOperation` and the `MergeOperation`) class extends `AbstractConflictDetectionOperation` that offers the `hasUnresolvedConflicts()` method. That does the trick ;)